# How do I get a Java Duration from a cron expression?

Tags: java, spring, cron, java-time

I have a scheduled task in a spring boot application:

```java
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${scheduled.task.rate}")
public void runScheduledTask() {
    // ...
}
```

With a corresponding test:

```java
@Test
public void test_scheduledTask_runs() {
    await().atMost(Duration.ofMillis(scheduledTaskRate).multipliedBy(2)).untilAsserted(() -> {
        Mockito.verify(scheduledTasks, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).runScheduledTask();
    });
}
```

Now I want to use a cron instead of a fixed rate:

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "${scheduled.task.cron}")
```

Now I need to adapt the test to this. How do get a `Duration` object corresponding to the frequency of the cron expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Spring specific solution:

Spring provides a [`CronExpression`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronExpression.html) class which can be used to [parse](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronExpression.html#parse-java.lang.String-) a cron expression and get the [next](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronExpression.html#next-T-) `Temporal` instance at which it will be triggered after the provided `Temporal`.

So to get a `Duration`:

```java
CronExpression cronExpression = CronExpression.parse(scheduledTaskCron);
LocalDateTime nextExecution = cronExpression.next(LocalDateTime.now());
LocalDateTime nextToNextExecution = cronExpression.next(nextExecution);
Duration durationBetweenExecutions = Duration.between(
        nextExecution, nextToNextExecution
);
```

Note that `Instant` can't be used as the `Temporal` here, as it can't represent all the components of a cron expression, such as `Day of Week`, giving the following exception:

```
java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: DayOfWeek
    at java.base/java.time.Instant.get(Instant.java:565)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronField$Type.get(CronField.java:200)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.BitsCronField.nextOrSame(BitsCronField.java:180)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronExpression.nextOrSameInternal(CronExpression.java:264)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronExpression.nextOrSame(CronExpression.java:252)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronExpression.next(CronExpression.java:245)
```

---

Original answer for spring versions < 5.3

Spring provides a [`CronSequenceGenerator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html) which can be used to parse a cron expression and get the [next](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html#next-java.util.Date-) `Date` instance at which it will be triggered after the provided `Date`.

So to get a `Duration`:

```java
CronSequenceGenerator generator = new CronSequenceGenerator(scheduledTaskCron);
Date nextExecution = generator.next(new Date());
Date nextToNextExecution = generator.next(nextExecution);
Duration durationBetweenExecutions = Duration.between(
        nextExecution.toInstant(), nextToNextExecution.toInstant()
);
```

Comment: CronSequenceGenerator is deprecated as of 5.3, in favour of CronExpression.parse(String). Usage of the new API to achieve the same thing is very similar.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @Tarmo, I've updated the answer (and also my code xD)

Comment: If somebody is stuck with an earlier version of Spring, beware that `CronSequenceGenerator` does not work all the time. For example, try `0 0/40 * ? * *` with the code that @aksh1618 shared. It returns 20 min.